# How to make string by removing Some from an object in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

How to make a string with comma separated by removing Some

```
case class Animal(name:Option[String], size:Option[Int]=None)

val animal = Animal(Some("apple"),Some(67))

val result = animal.productIterator.mkString(",").toString

//this gives: "Some(apple),Some(67)"

//How to get : "apple,67"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution of *Pritish* misses the `None` cases.

For example: `Animal(Some("apple"),None) //returns apple,None`

So If you are not happy with `None` int the list you can either replace it with a String or filter them out:

As String:

```
val result = animal.productIterator.map {
    case Some(x) => x
    case None => "[no value]"
    case x => x // only needed if you would have non optional values
  }.mkString(",") // > apple,[no value]
```

Filter them:

```
val result = animal.productIterator.map {
    case Some(x) => x
    case x => x 
  }.filter{
    case None => false
    case _ => true
  }.mkString(",") // > apple
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```scala
val result = animal.productIterator.map {
    case Some(x) => x
    case x => x
  }.mkString(",")
```